# Interchanging the order of integration

Tags: integration

My textbook says:

$$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\int_y^\infty f_Y(x)\ dx\ dy=\int_0^\infty\left(\int_0^xdy\right)f_Y(x)\ dx$$

Could someone please give me a step-by-step explanation of why this is true?

Answer (score 2):

On the left-hand side, you are integrating over the region that is above the horizontal $x$-axis and to the right of the line $y=x$.

On the right-hand side, you are integrating over the region between the lines $y=x$ and $y=0$ and to the right of the vertical $y$-axis.

If you draw a picture, these are the same regions.